# String.Format custom parameter placeholders

Tags: c#, string, format, string.format

I have a string `var str1 = "My name is {{0}}, I am {{1}} years old."`
I want to use `String.Format(str1, 'Pavel', 29)`;

Of course it does not work, because `String.Format()` expects parameter placeholders to be in a single curly brackets

So, I have to modify my string like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    str1 = str1.Replace("{{" + i + "}}", "{" + i + "}");
}
```

I wonder if there is a better way of doing it ? Is there a way I can define the format of the argument placeholders ?

Comment: you can supply the "outer"  `{` and `}` as params

Comment: Why does the original str1 have double braces in it to begin with? Is it supplied to you from somewhere you do not control?

Comment: @Mike, exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can define the format of the argument placeholders?

No.

> I wonder if there is a better way of doing it?

The only option you have is to make a format string that is compatible with `string.Format`. And that is what you have done now. If you can, fix the origin of those format strings.

If that is not possible, I would opt to use a regular expression to make this more robust and better performing.

The expression you should use is `{{(\d+)}}`, which can be replaced with `{$1}`. See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/KYV9pZ/3).